# Поиск адреса по метке в центре карты, как в Яндекс.Еда

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, input, геолокация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию поиска адреса при перетаскивании в центре карты, как в яндекс.еда и после вставить этот адрес в `<input name="adress" class="t-input js-tilda-rule">`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прослушивать изменение границ карты, геокодировать координаты её центра, а затем результат отправить в value поля так:

> ```
> myMap.events.add('boundschange', function () {
> ymaps.geocode(myMap.getCenter(), {
>     results: 1
> }).then(function (res) {
>         var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
>         address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();
>     });
> document.getElementsByClassName('t-input js-tilda-rule')[0].value=address;
> })
> ```

Сам же центр карты на Яндекс.Еде отображается не меткой, а наложенным поверх изображением, которое только помогает в прицеливании.