# Поиск адреса при драггинге карты + неподвижный маркер в центре карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, как инициализировать объект карты, чтобы в центре карты был маркер, который всегда остается **неподвижным**, а при перемещении (драггинге) карты получались координаты, которые находятся под данным маркером?

Пересмотрел всю документацию, но ничего подобного не нашел, хотя это вроде распространенная задача.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск адреса по карте, как в Яндекс.Еда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105259/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%95%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: Вам следует внимательней искать ответ здесь до написания вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119021/386299